# Deployment from Weblogic using Maven (Netbeans)

Tags: maven, netbeans, weblogic

Anyone know how it can make a starting deploy the weblogic using Maven application settings? Maven weblogic already managed to insert the plugins and dependencies but contrary to the way I have had problems. Any tips?

`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project jsf-scrumtoys:`

`Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.sun.faces:jsf-scrumtoys:war:0.1 from/to nexus-site (http://central_nexus/server): Failed to transfer file: http://central_nexus/server/com/sun/faces/jsf-scrumtoys/0.1/jsf-scrumtoys-0.1.war.`

`Return code is: 503, ReasonPhrase:Service Unavailable. -> [Help 1]`

`To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.`

`For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException`

Comment: Would you like to deploy an EAR/WAR into WebLogic app server?

Comment: Error message seems pretty straightforward: `Failed to transfer file: http://central_nexus/server/com/sun/faces/jsf-scrumtoys/0.1/jsf-scrumtoys-0.1.war`

Comment: Yes i would like to deplou a EAR into Weblogic app server, i can, validate, compile, test and install with maven, but i cant deploy.